# SQL Trigger: Update a column automatically when another column changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am writing a trigger so that whenever shareInterval changes, nextShareDate is automatically updated.

nextShareDate = today's date + shareInterval days.

```
Table: dbo.repeatShares

| repeatShareID | shareInterval | nextShareDate |
-------------------------------------------------
|       1       |       7       |  06/23/2014   |
-------------------------------------------------
|       2       |      14       |  06/30/2014   |
-------------------------------------------------
|       (many other rows in this table)         |
```

Here's what I have so far. It doesn't work; whenever I change shareInterval, nextShareDate doesn't change at all. Thanks!

```
USE [GFpermanent]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_updateNextShareDate]
ON [dbo].[repeatShares]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    IF UPDATE(shareInterval) RETURN; --Don't react recursively
    UPDATE 
        dbo.repeatShares
    SET 
        nextShareDate = DATEADD(day,shareInterval,getDate())
    WHERE 
        repeatShareID in (select repeatShareID from inserted)
```

Comment: I don't use sql-server but this line looks suspect to me: IF UPDATE(shareInterval) RETURN; shouldn't that be IF UPDATE(nextShareDate) RETURN;?

Comment: You are correct. I changed this, along with "from updated" to "from inserted" (on the last line), and now it works. Thanks! @ScottMildenberger

Comment: If you answer the question I will give you the "correct" checkmark @ScottMildenberger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the line below which just exits when the shareInterval is changed

IF UPDATE(shareInterval) RETURN;

to

IF UPDATE(nextShareDate) RETURN;

which will avoid the recursion.